# How do I install alsa-lib from launchpad?

Tags: alsa, launchpad

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-lib

What do I click on to install that for Vivid Vervet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`alsa-lib_1.0.28-1` is in the package `libasound2_1.0.28-1`, a shared library for ALSA applications.

To install open a terminal and install with:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2
```

---

Explanation:

On [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-lib), we read:

> **alsa-lib package in Ubuntu**
>   libasound2: shared library for ALSA applications
>   libasound2-data: Configuration files and profiles for ALSA drivers
>   libasound2-dbg: debugging symbols for libasound2
>   libasound2-dev: shared library for ALSA applications -- development files
>   libasound2-doc: documentation for user-space ALSA application programming
>   libasound2-udeb: shared library for ALSA applications (udeb)

Or we can start a search and count two and two together.:

```
apt-file search alsa-lib
```

Comment: Thank you that worked but how do I know in the future how to install from the launchpad like that.

Comment: I have improved my answer

Comment: You would also need to run `sudo apt-file update` before searching for a file.